# Configurable product price not changing. Help with Jquery conflict

Tags: configurable-product, jquery, magento-1.9.2

I have set up my simple products for my configurable product to change the price based upon size. It is working and adds to the cart at the correct price, but the price doesn't change dynamically on the product page.

[Here is the page to view it.](http://www.theframeroom.com/baltimore-md-panoramic-city-skyline-b-w-canvas-print-15.html)

I do see a lot of JQuery errors on the Inspect console of Chrome. This is admittedly an area of weakness in my dev game, so can anyone help me to resolve the conflict?

I think it's with the Olark chat, but I'm really excited to learn more about this and fixing this seems as good a time as any.

Comment: I turned off Olark and it didn't fix it. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Also removed the Mailchimp signup form in footer. No luck again.

Comment: Can you post your jQuery in a code block for us?

Comment: The JQuery call was what was suggested in the answer from Paul. I'm testing something else and an extension someone recommended tomorrow.